# Don't know what data structure to use for my algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to write my first algorithm and this is the pseudo code I am suppose to go off of. The algorithm is suppose to permute the set {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} for k spots. e.g n= set 0-9 so n=10 and r=k n^r permutations

so U={0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9} (singly linked list)
S is initially empty and let k=2. there should be 10^2 permutations of the set.  following the pseudo code step by step..

1) "remove e from U" and "add to the end of S"

```
U={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}

S={0}
```

2) it then does "PuzzleSolve(k-1,S,U)" again since k!= 1

```
U={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}
```

S={0,1} and k =1 now, so it checks for solutions. Assuming it doesn't find a solution.. the 1 goes back to U and is removed from S.

now:

```
U ={2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1}

S ={0}
```

so this keeps repeating until all the numbers in U get matched up with 0 because of the for loop in the first line. However my question is, how can I remove e from the end of S? I wanted to make S a linked list but I think it is impossible to remove a link from the end of a singly linked list. What data structure should I use for S?

```
Algorithm PuzzleSolve(k,S,U):

Input: Integer k, sequence S, and set U (universe of elements to test)

Output: Enumeration of all k-length extensions to S using elements in U without repetitions


**for** all e in U **do**
  Remove e from U {e is now being used}
  Add e to the end of S
  **if** k = 1 **then**
         Test whether S is a configuration that solves the puzzle
         **if** S solves the puzzle **then**
           **return** “Solution found: ” S
**else**
  PuzzleSolve(k - 1, S,U)
Add e back to U {e is now unused}
Remove e from the end of S
```

Comment: Create a conceptual model and translate it to Java.

Comment: I'll stay away from linked list and go with arrays, just to start with ... And I will use index to delimit the pieces of array for U and for S.

Comment: you can remove the last element in the linked list. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html#remove(int)

Comment: Are you allowed to use standard Java data structures?  If so, List most certainly allows you to remove the last element.  LinkedList is a double linked list (or performance equivalent), anyhow.

Comment: Don't let "algorithm" scare you away.  `A + B` is an algorithm.  First list all the data you need, including values that never change, values that change, and values that get created in bulk and must be stashed in a list or array or whatever.  Draw pictures of them.  If necessary add new values to keep track of, eg, how many you have in a list or array.  Don't get too balled up in trying to create "neat" objects just yet.

Comment: It is not very clear what you plan to do. First, why do you talk about "solving puzzles"? There isn't really any puzzle to solve. Just rearranging elements.

Comment: Second: what is exactly the output you want?
If you have n=10 and k=2 and you want permutation, (the word spots is misleading), if I understood what you want, you will have 10*9 permutation, not 10^2. And those will be:
{0,1}, {0,2},{0,3},{0,4},{0,5}, ...{1,0}, {1,2} and so on.
Is this what you want?

Comment: @azzurroverde I think the question needs refining. He is trying to convert his pseudo code to actual code. it looks like some stuff from university. So the algorithm is already told in the pseudo code. He also mentioned that he got blocked because he thinks he can't remove an element from the end of a linked list, so few mentioned that he can.

Comment: Yes, but from his description, it looks like he first needs to clarify the problem in his mind, then think about the algorithm. The title question is that he doesn;t know which data structure to use. Than he uses a list. A list is not the best solutiin for this problem. If his question is which data structure, my answer would be array. But then he needs to find a good algorithm for it.

Comment: You are using a recursive algorithm: is it required? If not, go for an iterative one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question you posted is a bit confusing because you wrote it as if we're sitting there next to you reading your homework... we're not. The pseudo-code describes a recursive, brute-force algorithm to solve a problem--try all possible solutions until we find one that works.

On the other hand, your question asks "the algorithm is supposed to permute the set for k spots". Er... not according to the pseudo-code.

From reading the pseudo-code, my understanding is that you start with a universe set:

```
{0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9}
```

And you want to try *all* "ordered k-tuples of the universe with no repeats". By that we mean:

```
(0, 1), (0, 2), (0, 3), ..., (0, 9)
(1, 0), (1, 2), (1, 3), ..., (1, 9)
(2, 0), (2, 1), (2, 3), ..., (2, 9)
...
(9, 0), (9, 1), (9, 2), ..., (9, 8)
```

This isn't necessary to write your code, but the number of "ordered k-tuples without repeats" can be described formulaically by `|U| * (|U| - 1) * ... * (|U| - k + 1)` or in this case:

```
10 * (10 - 1) => 90 (you can cross-check with the brute-force enumeration
above)
```

Now to answer your question, I would just use an `ArrayList` which is part of the base java libaries: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html.

You *don't want to code your own data structure if you don't need to*. The code backing `ArrayList` is non-trivial. I wouldn't try to emulate even parts of it unless your professor forbade you from using them. You *can* use a basic array, but abstraction is nice... why not use it? It'll be easier to implement that pseudo-code with an `ArrayList` because that pseudo-code translates almost identically to operations on `ArrayList`, such as `remove()` and `add()`.

If you wrote your own data structure you'd have to implement similar operations... which *could be part of the exercise*. If you are having trouble with that implementation, ask a new question in a separate post.

Answer (score 2):

In this case it would make sense to either use an array or arrayList. Since you already know the size of the set there is no need to use linked list. However, from your question it is not clear whether you must create your own structure or if you can use built-in structures. If it is the case that you cannot use an array, then you could implement a linked list. You should make your linked list iterable so that you can iterate through it with a for-each-loop.

Do you need help with creating a linked list?

Comment: yeah I created my own Linked List class but I don't know how to create a method to remove the last link. Is it possible?

Comment: The last link really isn't different from any other link.  It just happens to have next = null.  Removal is basically the same as any other node - traverse nodes until you find the node pointing to the one you want to remove.  So node->next = target.   Then set node->next = node->next->next.  In this case, the target has a null next, since it's the end, so now the node prior to the target has a null next, and becomes the end.

Comment: An easy way to remove the last element is using a doubly linked list with a pointer to the last element, when removing the last element you access its previous element and point that elements next to null. After that you change the last element pointer to point on this element. This way you don't use unnecessary operation on iterating through the whole list to get to the last item. It is good practice to have first and last pointers. Does this help or do you want code?

Answer (score 0):

Use an array, and use indexes:

```
int[] all; int u_begin, u_end, s_begin, s_end;
```

where

```
u_begin=0; u_end=10-k-1; s_begin=10-k, s_end=9;
```

Basically, the beginning of the array is U, the end is S, and you use an index to keep track of where the separation is.
I used 4 indexes to make you understand better, but actually only one is required, k, and you can calculate everything else from that.

When your code requires

```
Remove e from U {e is now being used}
  Add e to the end of S
```

Change the value of k, increasing it by 1.
And adapt your algorithm to use the array by modifying the index and by swapping elements appropriately.